# Google maps Autocomplete api not same as specifications

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm teasing google places API and I run into strange behavior at Autocomplete that I don't understand.

This is how I'm using it:

```
const AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTIONS = {
 types: ['address'],
 componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'cz'
 }
};
this.inputPlaceElement = $('#search-around-input')
this.inputPlaceSearchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.inputPlaceElement[0], AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTIONS);
google.maps.event.addListener(this.inputPlaceSearchBox,'places_changed', () => {
  console.log('place change')
})
```

Autocomplete input is working as it should but place_changed is not triggered, I was trying some stuf with it, and the object that is returned  from constructor is weird.
When I call methods getBounds() or getPlace() there are undefined

This is the object: I'm not sure what is wrong

[image: this is object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event triggered when a Place is selected is 'place_changed', while your sample uses 'place**s**_changed'

Try:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.inputPlaceSearchBox,'place_changed', function() {
  console.log('place change')
});
```